# How to execute external programs in the lookup table mechanism?

Tags: postfix

I need to execute a custom algorithm via header_checks lookup.

I have the configuration `smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes` to see in the headers what user is sending the message, eg:

`Received: from [0.0.0.0] (unknown [192.168.255.4])
    (Authenticated sender: myemail@mydomain.com)
    by smtp.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 08333374399
    for <geekygeeks@gmail.com>; Tue, 28 Oct 2008 10:45:37 -0400 (EDT)`

I need to make a mechanism to rewrite the `(Authenticated sender: myemail@mydomain.com)` to `(Authenticated sender: XXXXXX)` ... where `XXXXXX` is the md5sum of the email address (for security reasons).

Can I do this through the `header_checks` lookup table?

I know that this is possible, via an external daemon (a php or perl script, for example) that acts as server for the `TCP` or `SOCKETMAP` lookup table types, but is there a more simplified mechanism to archieve this?

Comment: I looked for that long ago, but I didn't found anything. I could easily develop that, if I had time for that.

Answer (score 2):

**Limitation: For this solution, you must list all your users and its md5. Except tcptable/external daemon solution, MD5 calculation doesn't supported by [most postfix table](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html)**

You can user pcre table and header_checks feature to achieves that. Specify this line in your header_check table. I tested this expression in pcre-type table.

```
/^(Received: .*Authenticated sender:)(.*?\))(.*)$/ REPLACE $1 md5ofstring) $3
```

References: [man header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) | [man pcre_table](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html)